# How to receive file csv from java with angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a rest api which returns a `file.csv`
and then I check that the response is `200`, and datas are also in `responsed.body`.

But the brower didn't download the csv file.

Here is the API :

```
ResponseEntity<Resource>  exportCsv() throws IOException {
    /*
     *
     */
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.csv");
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                         .headers(headers)
                         .contentLength(file.length())                 
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv"))
                         .body(resource);
}
```

Here is the Angular

```
this.stickService.exportCsv( this.stickSearch ).subscribe(
  response => this.downloadFile(response),
  err => console.log('Error downloading the file.'  + err.message 
));


downloadFile(data: Response) {
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}


exportCsv( stickSearch: StickSearch ): Observable<any> {
  const headers = this.oAuthService.putTokenInHeaders(this.headers);

  let params = new HttpParams({encoder: new HttpURIEncoder()});

  if (stickSearch.searchString() !== '') {
    params = params
    .append('search', stickSearch.searchString())
  }

  return this.httpClient.get(this.exportCsvUrl + '/exportCsv',
  {
    responseType: 'text',
    params: params,
    headers
  });
}
```

I got correct data at response body.

But the download failed.  `'Error downloading the file.Http failure during parsing for myURL '`

Thanks for helping

It work now, this is consequence
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202784/angular-springboot-downlod-excel-file-httperrorresponse/57204161#comment101030766_57204161

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are taking the output provided by the server and then building an URL off that CSV. That won't be necessary.
If you just want to download the CSV, then all you are missing is the following in your Java code:

```
headers.add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.csv");
```

Once you have the header in place, you can get rid of the `downloadFile` method and probably change the `this.httpClient.get` request into a `window.open`.

See if this solves your problem and provide feedback in either case.

Comment: Now that, if call by API,  I can download file.csv after add your headers, thanks you
But in anguler didn't, still Error downloading the file.Http failure during parsing for h <myURL>

Answer (score 0):

By default `HttpClient` expects that data from server will come in `json` format. Angular tries to parse text body as json. And that leads to exсeption. In the `stickService` when you do request the data, you have to specify type or result as `text`:

```
constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient){
}

public exportCsv(stickSearch: any) {
    return httpClient.get('http://someurl', {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

Another one point that you use `window.open(url)`. Most browsers block popup windows by default. So maybe it would be better to use an anchor element.

```
downloadFile(data: Response) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.download = 'myfile.txt'; // here you can specify file name
    anchor.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
}
```

Comment: I can't set responseType to 'text'  ;


TS2345: Type "text" is not assignable to type "json"

Comment: @a4fz067lu Remove generic parameter when call http methods. For example  if you call `put` method, it has to be `put(...)` instead of `put<string>(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the I'm using for this feature.
First, use 'Accept' headers.
Second, set responseType to 'text', the default is 'json'.
Third, the download code.

```
getCsv(): Observable<any> {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/csv');

  return this.http.get('SOME__URL', {
    headers: headers,
    responseType: 'text'
  });
}

exportReportCSV() {
  getCsv().subscribe( response => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response], {type: 'text/csv'}));
    link.download = this.report.name + '.csv';
    link.click();
});
```

Comment: I can't set responseType to 'text' ; TS2345: Type "text" is not assignable to type "json"

Comment: That's a reported issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586.
But if you set the options in line as I described it should do it.