# Consuming Spring Boot StreamingResponseBody from Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which serves 100's of images zipped and sent over StreamingResponseBody, Is there a way to consume this service from an angular application?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/initialize")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> initializeSlider(final HttpServletResponse response,
                                                              String axis,String nodeId) {
    Long totalCount = imageRepository.countImageByAxisAndNodeId(axis,nodeId);

    int interval =  Math.round(totalCount / 50) ;

    List<Integer> sequenceList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<totalCount;i=i+interval){
        int nextSequence = i + interval;
        sequenceList.add(nextSequence);
    }

    System.out.println(sequenceList.toString());
    System.out.println(sequenceList);

    response.setContentType("application/zip");
 //   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.zip");

    StreamingResponseBody stream = out -> {
        final ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        List<Image> imageList = imageRepository.findImageBySequenceIdIn(sequenceList);

        try {
            imageList.stream().forEach(image -> {
                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                    oos.writeObject(image);
                    oos.flush();
                    byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
                    final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                    final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(image.getName());
                    zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    //IOUtils.copy(inputStream,zipOut);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = inputStream.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                        zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                    }
                    zipOut.closeEntry();
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            zipOut.flush();
            zipOut.close();
        }
    };

    System.out.println(stream);
    logger.info("steaming response {} ", stream);
    return new ResponseEntity(stream, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202784/angular-springboot-downlod-excel-file-httperrorresponse/57204161#comment101030766_57204161

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using `{ responseType: 'blob' }` as options.

To download the file you can use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

`import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`

```
this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe((resp: any) => {
    FileSaver.saveAs(resp, `abc.zip`);
})
```