# Unable to export excel (xlsm) in angular 7 - with spring boot backend

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spring-boot, filesaver.js

I have a Spring Boot controller for the export to excel feature

The Problem is that after downloading excel says file is corrupted and never opens.
What is wrong in the code? I know this is related to character encoding as when I download the same file via postman (using save file feature) the file opens smoothly. I see some binary characters difference if I open the postman format and angular format.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202784/angular-springboot-downlod-excel-file-httperrorresponse/57248351#57248351

Comment: I finally solved the issue by introducing anchor tag in html code - <a href="/download/file.xlsm/{{selecteddate}}" target="_blank" download="file.xlsm"></a> .    This doesnt require any angular/typescript code.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `responseType`value in your `exportAlluserData()` method:

```
responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
```

Replace it with: `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`.

Comment: Still same error comes after changing to arraybuffer.

Comment: @FKMN Does API return the correct file but from angular it's corrupted? can you remove `charset=unicode` from everywhere?

Comment: I have removed and tried. Still same problem. Is this the correct way of doing it? I am returning xlsm file with macro enabled in it from spring boot backend.